# MySQL SELECT WHERE 'a' IN (`field`)

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I know it is not an appropriate technique to have a structure of MySQL table as such, but I have to work with such. The problem is, that the field in table has value with comma seperated integers, like "1,3,5,7,10" and I want the query to return rows, in which `field` has a to the query passed number in it, like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '5' IN (`field_in_table`)
```

However, it does not work, if, in this case, '5' is not the first number in the field.
Any advises, how to solve that?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at

[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N
>   if the string str is in the string
>   list strlist consisting of N
>   substrings. A string list is a string
>   composed of substrings separated by
>   “,” characters. If the first argument
>   is a constant string and the second is
>   a column of type SET, the
>   FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to
>   use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if str
>   is not in strlist or if strlist is the
>   empty string.

Comment: Thanks - this is the functionality, which I was looking for. I simplyg forgot this command :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WHERE field_in_table LIKE '%5%'` instead.
Of course, the problem would be, '1,59,98' would return as wel.

Comment: It won't work, because it will return it either it will be 50 or 5 :S

Comment: Better make that '%,5,%' if you're looking for '5' only and not '25' or '51' too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_in_table LIKE '%5'");
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE '%,5,%' LIKE field_in_table OR
          '%,5'   LIKE field_in_table OR
          '5,%'   LIKE field_in_table;
```

A better approach might be to use regular expressions, a subject on which I am not an authority.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE FIELD LIKE '%,5,%' OR 
      FIELD LIKE '5,%' OR 
      FIELD LIKE '%,5'
```